# A function that maps Held symbol to string

Tags: hold, symbols, variable, string-manipulation

Rougly my question is about constructing a function that maps Hold[var] to "var"
even when var has an assigned value. In details :

```
In[1] var=22; A=Hold[var];
```

Can we construct a function F such that
F[A] becomes the string, "var" ?

In fact, I can do it like :

```
In[2] F[x_]:=StringDrop[StringDrop[ToString[x],5],-1];
In[3] F[A]//InputForm
Out[3] "var"
```

But above method seems somewhat unnatural.

One natural,ideal way I think possible is :

1. uncover Hold in Hold[var], with its content(=var) untouched,
   and apply ToString to the content.

Another natural,ideal way I think possible is :

2. Change Hold in Hold[var] to ToString, with its content(=var) untouched.

Can you suggest natural ways to do it?

Comment: How about: `F[Hold[x_]] := ToString@Unevaluated@x`?

Comment: (Also, not sure if you're using this in a larger context, but `SetAttributes[F, HoldFirst]`, `F[x_] := ToString@Unevaluated@x` lets you dispense with the `Hold` and use `F[var]` directly, in case that's useful to you!)

Comment: Thank you answeres! Solved my problem.

Comment: An option using `SymbolName` and pure function syntax `Function[Null, SymbolName[Unevaluated[#]], HoldFirst]`

Comment: Thank you b3m2a1. Could you write the code in detail? I just typed Function[Null, SymbolName[Unevaluated[#]], HoldFirst]&[A] but seems not working well.

Comment: `&` is short for `Function`, so it's redundant here (even though the syntax highlighter doesn't get that `#` is bound). try simply `Function[Null, SymbolName[Unevaluated[#]], HoldFirst][A]`. Equivalently, `Function[v, SymbolName[Unevaluated[v]], HoldFirst][A]`

Comment: Thank you I undertood.